# Python 3 - Controle de Fluxo inesperado ao executar IF/IF NOT ou IF/ELSE

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

Eu sou novo em Python, mas já tenho costume programa em Java.

Gostaria de entender melhor o porquê ao tentar programar um controle de fluxo usando IF/ELSE ou IF/IF NOT o bloco todo é executado.

#### Código Python 3.7

```py
luz_acessa = False
def interruptor():
    global luz_acessa
    if luz_acessa:
        print("True: Luz acessa")
        luz_acessa = False
    if not luz_acessa: // Mesma coisa com 'else' ao invés de 'if not'
        print("False: Luz apagada")
        luz_acessa = True
```

#### Console Python 3.7

```
interruptor()
False: Luz apagada
interruptor()
True: Luz acessa
False: Luz apagada
interruptor()
True: Luz acessa
False: Luz apagada
interruptor()
True: Luz acessa
False: Luz apagada
```

---

Por exemplo em Java, se eu quiser inverter um boolean faço algo simples assim:

#### Código Java:

```java
private boolean luz_ligada;
    private void interruptor(){
        if(luz_ligada){
            System.out.println("Luz acessa");
            luz_ligada = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Luz apagada");
            luz_ligada = true;
        }
    }
```

#### Log Java em um simples loop:

```
Luz apagada
Luz acessa
Luz apagada
Luz acessa
Luz apagada

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os códigos não são equivalentes. `if not` não é o mesmo que `else`.

Em Java, o equivalente ao que você escreveu em Python é:

```
private boolean luz_ligada;
private void interruptor(){
    if(luz_ligada){
        System.out.println("Luz acessa");
        luz_ligada = false;
    }

    if(!luz_ligada) {
        System.out.println("Luz apagada");
        luz_ligada = true;
    }
}
```

Para terem o mesmo resultado, você deve alterar o código Python para:

```
luz_acessa = False
def interruptor():
    global luz_acessa
    if luz_acessa:
        print("True: Luz acessa")
        luz_acessa = False
    else:
        print("False: Luz apagada")
        luz_acessa = True
```

Answer (score 2):

A resposta dada pelo Leonardo Lima está correta, mas apenas uma explicação mais aprofundada do porque.

De modo geral é bem simples.
Veja a seguir a diferença deste código:

```
luz_acessa = False

def interruptor():
    global luz_acessa
    if luz_acessa:
        print("True: Luz acessa")
        luz_acessa = False
    else:
        print("False: Luz apagada")
        luz_acessa = True
```

para esse código:

```
luz_acessa = False

def interruptor():
    global luz_acessa
    if luz_acessa:
        print("True: Luz acessa")
        luz_acessa = False
    if not luz_acessa:
        print("False: Luz apagada")
        luz_acessa = True
```

e para um terceiro exemplo não citado antes:

```
luz_acessa = False

def interruptor():
    global luz_acessa
    if luz_acessa:
        print("True: Luz acessa")
        luz_acessa = False
    elif not luz_acessa:
        print("False: Luz apagada")
        luz_acessa = True
```

O `if`, é nada mais nada menos que um operador condicional em nível de código, é um `branch` em nível de processador, mas focando no nível de código, ele tem por objetivo verificar a veracidade da informação colocada após ele. se estas forem verdadeiras ele executa o código que o segue.

Ao usar o `else` cria-se um caminho para quando a informação colocada no primeiro for falsa, ou seja:

```
Se a luz estiver acesa:

   Apague

Senão:

   Acenda

Fim Se
```

No código que você postou, como não usou o operador `else` para quando a informação for falsa, e ao invés disso utilizou outro operador `if` o que faria com que o código verificasse cada uma de forma separada e as execute uma a uma, e não de forma dependente, segue exemplo de como seu código executava:

```
Se a luz estiver acesa:

   Apague

Fim Se

Se a luz estiver apagada:

   Acenda

Fim Se
```

Isso exemplifica, que sempre que o sua função for executada, os dois executarão em seguida, fazendo com que o primeiro `if` sempre seja sobrescrito

Quanto ao exemplo citado por mim, o `else` como já citado cria um caminho para quando a informação é falsa, a diferença deste para o `else if`, é que o `else if` cria um caminho para quando a primeira informação for falsa, porém a sua informação for verdadeira, segue exemplo da execução:

```
Se a luz estiver acesa:

   Apague

Senão, se a luz estiver apagada:

   Acenda

Fim Se
```

Supondo que a `luz` tivesse um terceiro valor que fosse diferente de `true` ou `false`, por exemplo um `indefinido`, quando a luz estivesse com valor `indefinido` ela não seria nem acesa e nem apagada, e para alterar isso teria que, ou colocar outro `else if` que verificasse quando for indefinida, ou colocar um `else` ao final de tudo para que este seja sempre executado quando os anteriores não forem.

Enfim, espero ter ajudado